# Mysql Workbench Data export, no access for user with full privileges

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, data-export

I am using MySQL Workbench to access a remote DB server from my desktop.
The problem is that I can create and modify databases but not export a DB to a SQL file nor import to them from a SQL file on my computer.

When i look at the user privileges for the root user it has all check-boxes for "administrative roles" and "Global privileges" checked.

When I am trying to import a local SQL file to my remote server I get a password prompt and I enter the correct password, but I constantly get error:

```
15:36:24 Restoring G:\xxxxxx.sql

Running: mysql.exe --defaults-extra-file="c:\users\andreas\appdata\local\temp\tmp4_ji5c.cnf"  --host=xx.xx.xx.xx --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments < "G:\\xxxxxxx.sql"

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'xxx.zz' (using password: YES)

Operation failed with exitcode 1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in my.cnf I had 0.0.0.0 set for "bind-address".
Setting that value to the correct IP solved the problem.

I think its weird that I managed to do everything else but import/export when bind-adress was set to 0.0.0.0....